# What operator do we use to measure at the end of a quantum search algorithm?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Perhaps an obvious question, but I do not have the answer to it, so I though I would still ask.

In the below quantum search algorithm, also known as Grover's algorithm, what operator are we measuring at the end of the procedure?  That is, in the red box, it says "measure the first $n$ qubits", but what *operator* are we using to measure these qubits?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: hi Stephen, the operator measured is the qubit that is transformed by the oracle. You might have better luck asking this in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MohammadAthar Hi, thanks for the reply and the link.  I meant to say, what operator are we **using to make** the measurement on these $n$ qubits?

Comment: I think they are vague on this point due to there not being a "standard" qubit. A qubit could be related to the spin state of atom, two electronic states, the polarization of light, etc and all of these would have a different operator to measure the state.

Comment: @Tyberius I see, it does seem plausible, indeed.  Thanks. I have also posted the question on the quantum-computing s.e. - perhaps, I'll get more clarification there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's some confusion in your question in the phrase "use an operator to make a measurement". There are two things you can do with an operator:

1) Unitary operators are examples of *channels*. They change the state of the system, you 'use them' by actually acting on the state: $|\psi\rangle \mapsto \hat{U} |\psi\rangle$.

2) Hermitian operators are *observables*. This is a completely distinct type of thing and it's pedagogically unfortunate that both channels and observables can be represented as matrices. One 'measures' a Hermitian operator but this is actually code for a very complicated channel/unitary evolution. We usually ignore the implementation of that, and just describe the set of possible end states and measurement results. Such a spectrum $\{(\lambda_i,|\lambda_i\rangle) \}_{i=1,\dots,N}$ is best described by a Hermitian matrix $X= \sum_i |\lambda\rangle \lambda_i \langle \lambda |$.

This is a long way to say: you just need to pick an operator whose eigenstates are the possible states of the qubits, and whose eigenvalues are all distinct. In the case of a single qubit, this just corresponds to $\sigma_z$:

$$ \sigma_z = |0\rangle\langle 0 | - |1\rangle \langle 1 |\sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

For $N$ qubits you can simply measure $\sigma_z$ on each qubit (ie operators like $\mathbf{1}_2\otimes \dots \otimes \sigma_z \otimes \dots \mathbf{1}_2$$). These all commute so you can simply measure the set of all of them and this should work.

Comment: It's amazing that this was not mentioned in my quantum computation class. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a follow up question please.  In the N qubits case, when measuring the operators of the form $1 \otimes Z \otimes 1 \otimes... $, my understanding is that each next measurement is done on the outcome state of the previous measurement that we made, right? So, e.g. if after measuring the first qubi, the initial state collapses to the outcome state $|v>$, then the measurement of the second qubit is made on the collapsed state $|v>$? and so on...  In that case, can I simply measure the observable $Z \otimes Z \otimes... \otimes Z$ on all  N qubits?

Comment: The set of operators that I listed is not the same as the single operator $Z\otimes \dots \otimes Z$. The latter would not be able to distinguish which spins are up since all a measurement reports is the eigenvalue and this is only dependent on how many spins are up.

Answer (score 0):

Measurement is not described as applying an operator, but rather a more general [quantum operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_operation#Quantum_measurement) which transforms your pure state into a mixed state.